# Actionbar spinner with title and email status like gmail app

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, spinner

I am working on a email app and trying to include default title and subtitle into a spinner. When the user clicks on it, I want it to show a drop down menu with mail folders.

[image]

This is the code which I want to convert into a spinner:

```
View customView = mActionBar.getCustomView();

mTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.title);
mSubTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.status);
```

Layout for this TextView

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_message_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:singleLine="true"
              android:textColor="?attr/richcolor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
               android:textColor="?attr/richcolor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you already try anything yourself to tackle this problem? Also, your post contains a reference to a picture but there is no reference in the text. Maybe you want to edit your post to actually have a link to it in the text?

Comment: I tried hard to solve the problem, but I did not find any useful info . here is the link which shows a sample image http://i.stack.imgur.com/79Xzr.png